# Como criar um PDF usando iText para Android

Tags: android, pdf, itext

Eu estava tentando criar um arquivo pdf em minha aplicação Android, como não encontrava nada que funcionasse, hoje consegui resolver o problema por conta própria. Segue o código a quem interessar.

Aqui estão os imports correspondentes ao iText.jar

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
```

Aqui o código funcionando perfeitamente

```
private void criandoPdf() {

    try {

         String filename = "teste.pdf";

        document = new Document(PageSize.A4);

        String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) + "/MeuPdf";

        File dir = new File(path, filename);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }

        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(dir);
        fOut.flush();

        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fOut);
        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph("Aqui esta meu pdf"));


    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        document.close();
    }

}
```

Se alguém souber trabalhar bem com o iText, sinta-se a vontade para postar um bom link para implementação de funcionalidades mais avançadas tais como, inserir bordas e linhas. Não é uma pergunta, apenas poste qualquer coisa relevante, apenas para agregar e ajudar quem estiver tentando o mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja o gist que criei abaixo, talvez ainda possa ser útil para você.

[pdf](https://gist.github.com/jcaiqueoliveira/ae5535f16cb2095f210d)

Comment: Obrigado amigo, é muito útil sim. Segue aqui um link com algumas funções básicas a quem precisar criar uma tabela. http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=152

Answer (score 0):

Alguém sabe como criar um PDF que espelha um Holerite(Contracheque)?

Eu estava imaginando em 2 opções:
A primeira é criando um XML que representa todo o layout do contracheque, assim me facilitaria na inserção dos campos e a organização.

A segunda é através de um imagem, e colocaria as informações conforme as margens de alinhamento.

No meu ponto de visão a primeira seria a mais viável, alguém poderia me dar um Norte para eu prosseguir?

Comment: Yuri, Bem vindo ao SOpt, antes de começar de uma olhada em nosso [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)  O local onde você publicou sua pergunta é apenas para respostas, sua mensagem poderia ser um comentário da pergunta, no entanto você ainda não possui reputação suficiente para tal. Sugiro que você abra uma pergunta própria explicando seu problema, porém antes leia [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)